# How do you run headless chrome driver and a proxy using selenium in python?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

This is how I set up proxy for the headless chrome driver:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

PROXY = "137.220.34.109:8080" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r"C:\Users\Ertan\Downloads\chromedriver.exe")
chrome.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com")
```

This is the code I use to run selenium with the headless driver:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

import time

options = Options()
options.headless = True
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Users\Ertan\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')

browser.get("https://www.google.com")
time.sleep(4)
browser.get_screenshot_as_file("headless.png")
```

How do I change my code to run headless through a proxy? How to merge the `Options` and `ChromeOptions` simultaneously?